# how can I write the map inside map in dataweave in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

how can I write the map inside map in dataweave in mule.
Example while transforming from XML to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add any sample input so that we can suggest better?

In general, you can nest `map` as long as the objects you want to iterate on are collections. But remember, in case of CSV, you cannot have nested properties in output.

Comment: <Root>
 <A>
  <B>
  </B>
  <C>
 <D>
 <id>123</id>
 </D>
 <D>
 <id>433</id>
 </D>
 <E>
 <name>John</name>
 </E>
 <E>
 <name>suresh</name>
 </E>
 <E>
 <name>Siva</name>
 </E>
  </C>
 </A>

Comment: PF above xml to use case.Inside D tag we have different ID's. Every Id has all the below names(available in E tag) to each ID.we have to iterate in dataweave. Note: D and E are in same level inside the C tag.

Comment: how it has to come is 123 John 123 suresh 123 Siva 433 John 433 suresh 433 siva

Comment: so you mean payload.Root.A.*C should map and output a single row with id-name pair and every name should be tied to each id? Are you sure this is the exact payload example you are trying to map? You can map over C and nest it with map on D.

Comment: As of now we are mapping over E which is nested inside mapping over on D. This generates proper match, but it generates multiple headers. Moreover all records come in same row and not one beneath the other

Comment: Can you post your dataweave script?

Comment: %dw 1.0
%var mroot=payload.root.*A
%output application/csv header=true
---

[{(mroot map using (sv=$.B.SV) {
       

  ($.C.*D  map using (id=$.id)  {

              
              ( C.*E  map {
                           
                     
                     id:id,
                     Name:$.name
                     
              })
       })
})
}]

Comment: Little odd structure, `%dw 1.0 
%var mroot=payload.root.*A 
%output application/csv header=true 
---
using (etags = payload.root.A.C.*D.*id) (payload.root.A.C.*E map ((dval,dpos) -> ({
   (etags map ((eval,epos) -> ({
    id: eval,
    name: dval.name
   })))
  }))
)` .... not the exact solution yet. You can have multiple A?

Answer (score 0):

Use a splitter based on D and store the ID in flow Variable and use setpayload inside splitter and map the Id with names and use collector to collect all the results.See the below sample I didnt do the dataweave transformation but I have given you a high level idea

```
<flow name="sampleFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/Root/A/C/D')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
        <set-variable variableName="storeId" value="#[xpath3('/id')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.originalPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
    </flow>
```